# R - Composite functions vs piped functions in `purrr::map()`

Tags: r, data-manipulation, purrr

I have the following list:

```
my_list = list(alpha = list('hi'), 
               beta = list(1:4, 'how'), 
               gamma = list(TRUE, FALSE, 'are'))
str(my_list)

List of 3
 $ alpha:List of 1
  ..$ : chr "hi"
 $ beta :List of 2
  ..$ : int [1:4] 1 2 3 4
  ..$ : chr "how"
 $ gamma:List of 3
  ..$ : logi TRUE
  ..$ : logi FALSE
  ..$ : chr "are"
```

I would like to figure out which data types are contained within each level 1 element. To do this, I can use the following pipeline:

```
piped = map(my_list, ~map(., class) %>% unique %>% unlist)
str(piped)
List of 3
 $ alpha: chr "character"
 $ beta : chr [1:2] "integer" "character"
 $ gamma: chr [1:2] "logical" "character"
```

...which works as expected. But when I try to nest the call to `unique` inside `unlist()`, I get something different:

```
composite = map(my_list, ~map(., class) %>% unlist(unique(.)))
str(composite)
List of 3
 $ alpha: chr "character"
 $ beta : chr [1:2] "integer" "character"
 $ gamma: chr [1:3] "logical" "logical" "character"
```

Could someone please help me understand why these two approaches are not equivalent?

Comment: I think the two uses of the dot are in different scopes, leading to the unexpected behavior but can't quite tease it out.

Comment: Thanks for your input @pgcudahy, I tried using `unique(.x)` in place of `unique(.)` but got the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to see what's happening if you use anonymous functions rather than the dot notation.

`piped = map(my_list, ~map(., class) %>% unique %>% unlist)` is the same as

`piped = map(my_list, function (x) map(x, class) %>% unique %>% unlist)`

The pipe then places the output of each step in the first position of each subsequent function, so it becomes

`piped = map(my_list, function (x) unique(map(x, class)) %>% unlist)` and then

`piped = map(my_list, function (x) unlist(unique(map(x, class))))`

Which results is

```
str(piped)
List of 3
 $ alpha: chr "character"
 $ beta : chr [1:2] "integer" "character"
 $ gamma: chr [1:2] "logical" "character"
```

Similarly `composite = map(my_list, ~map(., class) %>% unlist(unique(.)))`

can be written as

`composite = map(my_list, function(x) map(x, class) %>% unlist(unique(x)))`

The two uses of x on both sides of the pipe is where things go weird. I think you were expecting the pipe to place the output of the inner map call in place of the x within the `unique` call, but the second x takes the output from the outer map function. Instead the pipe does its default action and places the output of the inner map call in the first position of the `unlist` function, like so

`composite = map(my_list, function(x) unlist(map(x, class),unique(x)))`

Which gives you

```
str(composite)
List of 3
 $ alpha: chr "character"
 $ beta : chr [1:2] "integer" "character"
 $ gamma: chr [1:3] "logical" "logical" "character"
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that so thoroughly @pgcudahy! Writing the pipeline out in this way really helped my understanding. Is this the same reason as to why using `.x` in place of the second `.` didn't work? I'm not sure what `map(., ~map(., class) %>% unlist(unique(.x)))` evaluates to (`map(my_list, function(x) map(x, class) %>% unlist(unique(.x)))`?) and how the `.x` is scoped.