# Set the second element of a nested list to the list's element's name (purrr)

Tags: r, list, tidyverse, purrr, nested-lists

I have a named list of lists with empty elements that I want to fill in:

```
List of 3
 $ name1:List of 3
  ..$ A: NULL
  ..$ B: NULL
  ..$ C: NULL
 $ name2:List of 3
  ..$ I: NULL
  ..$ J: NULL
  ..$ K: NULL
 $ name3:List of 3
  ..$ P: NULL
  ..$ Q: NULL
  ..$ R: NULL
```

I can assign a vector to, let's say, a second element of each sub-list:

```
testlist <- map(testlist, ~modify_at(.x, 2, ~c("one", "two", "three")))
str(testlist)

List of 3
 $ name1:List of 3
  ..$ A: NULL
  ..$ B: chr [1:3] "one" "two" "three"
  ..$ C: NULL
 $ name2:List of 3
  ..$ I: NULL
  ..$ J: chr [1:3] "one" "two" "three"
  ..$ K: NULL
 $ name3:List of 3
  ..$ P: NULL
  ..$ Q: chr [1:3] "one" "two" "three"
  ..$ R: NULL
```

But now I want to assign a name of each element of the list to the third element of each sub-lists (ie the name of that element will be different in every turn of the loop). Desired output:

```
List of 3
 $ name1:List of 3
  ..$ A: NULL
  ..$ B: NULL
  ..$ C: chr "name1"
 $ name2:List of 3
  ..$ I: NULL
  ..$ J: NULL
  ..$ K: chr "name2"
 $ name3:List of 3
  ..$ P: NULL
  ..$ Q: NULL
  ..$ R: chr "name3"
```

And a simple modification of the previous function doesn't work:

`map(testlist, ~modify_at(.x, 3, ~.x))`

When I do this, the third element of each sub-list entirely dissapears:

```
List of 3
 $ name1:List of 2
  ..$ A: NULL
  ..$ B: NULL
 $ name2:List of 2
  ..$ I: NULL
  ..$ J: NULL
 $ name3:List of 2
  ..$ P: NULL
  ..$ Q: NULL
```

I tried various combinations, including set_names(.x) or even map2:

`map2(testlist, names(testlist), ~modify_at(.x, 3, ~.y))`

(The last bit is equivalent to imap)

But nothing works and many of them result in the removal of the third element of each sub-list. And there is nothing wrong with the names of the main list.

```
names(testlist)
[1] "name1" "name2" "name3"
```

I am not quite sure what is going on there. Any hints and help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to [R - Composite functions vs piped functions in `purrr::map()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57840592/r-composite-functions-vs-piped-functions-in-purrrmap/57841987#57841987), it's easier to see what's happening when you use anonymous functions rather than the formula (~) notation.

Start with

```
testlist  <- list(name1=list(NULL,NULL,NULL), name2=list(NULL,NULL,NULL),
name3=list(NULL,NULL,NULL))

str(testlist)
#> List of 3
#>  $ name1:List of 3
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>  $ name2:List of 3
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>  $ name3:List of 3
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : NULL
```

Then to recreate your first example
`testlist2 <- map(testlist, ~modify_at(.x, 2, ~c("one", "two", "three")))` can be rewritten as `testlist2_expand <- map(testlist, function(x) modify_at(x, 2, function(y) y=c("one", "two", "three")))` which gives the same output for `str(testlist2_expand)` of

```
#> List of 3
#>  $ name1:List of 3
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : chr [1:3] "one" "two" "three"
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>  $ name2:List of 3
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : chr [1:3] "one" "two" "three"
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>  $ name3:List of 3
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : chr [1:3] "one" "two" "three"
#>   ..$ : NULL
```

But your second example `map(testlist, ~modify_at(.x, 3, ~.x))` is really
`map(testlist, function(x) modify_at(x, 1, function (y) y = y))`

I think you expected the .x to get reused, but it is a new variable in a new scope. It's never defined so gets evaluated as NULL, leading to `map(testlist, function(x) modify_at(x, 1, function (y) NULL))` and the element is removed

To do what you want

```
testlist2 <- map2(testlist, names(testlist), function(x,y) modify_at(x, 3, function (z) z = y))
str(testlist2)
#> List of 3
#>  $ name1:List of 3
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : chr "name1"
#>  $ name2:List of 3
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : chr "name2"
#>  $ name3:List of 3
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : chr "name3"
```

Comment: >I think you expected the .x to get reused
That's exactly what I thought was happening... Your answer explains this - genius! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Having said that, I can't figure out what the shorthand notation should be like in this case (or if shorthand notation is possible in the first place), in particular using `imap`, which is designed for cases like this (I think).
The modification of your answer with `imap` is simple and working when the function is fully specified:
`imap(testlist, function(x,y) modify_at(x, 2, function (z) z = y))`
But not when any shorthand notation I could come up with is implemented.

Comment: You could pass it with a quosure `testlist2 <- map2(testlist, names(testlist), ~ modify_at(.x, 3, quo(.y)))` which I still don't fully understand. You can read about it at https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html